# Cannot import perspective in Eclipse Kepler

Tags: eclipse, ide, eclipse-juno, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-kepler

I used to share Eclipse CDT perspectives across machines and workspaces of the same machine by exporting preferences to a file and then importing it where needed.

It worked in Juno version but now when I am doing the same in Kepler the perspective simply is not listed though it appears in:

```
org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi
org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.workbench.prefs
org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.ui.prefs
org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/org.eclipse.debug.ui.prefs
```

How can I debug this? Any logs to check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is probably covered by these Eclipse bugs [385920](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=385920) and [378811](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=378811). Scheduled to be fixed in Eclipse 4.4M5

Comment: Thanks for the tickets. I followed Jim Taller's suggestion in 378811 and copied .metadata/.plugin/org.eclipse.e4.workbench/workbench.xmi into a new workspace which gave me the desired perspective.